# How to make babel/register affect on imported files?

Tags: node.js, babeljs, babel-node, babel-register

Below `gulpfile.babel.js` runs without error by `babel-node gulpfile.babel.js` (I know that to execute the gulp task I should to run `gulp taskname`, but `babel-node gulpfile.babel.js` is for debugging without running tasks).

```
require('@babel/register');
import gulp from 'gulp';

gulp.task('default', done => {
  console.log('No problem!');
  done();
});
```

If to include file (`node-modules/my-config-helper/index.js` in this example) which also contains `import` or `export` keywords,  error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token export` will occur.

```
require('@babel/register');
import gulp from 'gulp';

import ConfigHelper from 'my-config-helper';
```

### node-modules/my-config-helper/index.js

```
require('@babel/register');

export default class ConfigHelper {
  constructor() {
    console.log('ConfigHelper: done');
  }
}
```

Looks like `require('@babel/register');` affects only a single file but not to includes. O'K, what should I do? Just install `babel-core` and `babel-register` in `my-config-helper` in not enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the ES syntax into another file, and require that file from your index.js:

```
// index.js
require('@babel/register');
require("./gulp-stuff"); <-- from this point on - all ES code will be transpiled

// gulp-stuff.js
import gulp from 'gulp';
import ConfigHelper from './my-config-helper';
// ....


// my-config-helper.js
export default class ConfigHelper {
  constructor() {
    console.log('ConfigHelper: done');
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I see... Thank you for the answer!

Comment: how to use `import` statements in `index.js` and transpile everything in `index.js` *and* everything that subsequently gets imported too, regardless of the folder it is in (except for `/node_modules`)?